# Topology resources / exercises

Tags: general-topology, online-resources

I'm looking for some basic Topology exercises. Like:

- Determine the interior of a set in the given metric
- Is this set is a border set
- Is this space a Complete metric space
- Is this family a base
- Is this space a Separable space

Things around this scope

Comment: All math books have lists of exercises, don't they?

Comment: I cannot find any. That's the problem. I have been looking for them for a month now. I have hardly found anything.